# texi2dvi with TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015) in R is not working

Tags: latex, r, texlive

In past I was using

```
texi2dvi("ABC.tex", pdf = TRUE)
```

in `R` to produce `pdf` from `tex`. However, after using

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now using

```
texi2dvi("ABC.tex", pdf = TRUE)
```

throws the following error

```
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'ABC.tex' failed.
Messages:
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Yaseen/XYZ’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/texi2dvi: cannot create directory: Yaseen/XYZ
```

My directory name contains spaces too (I can not change because many my directories have spaces in their names).

Through surfing I came across this [link](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html) which says:

> To build the PDF documentation, you will need a version of TeX Live or texinfo that includes texi2dvi (BEWARE: recent TeX Live, and some texinfo RPMs, do NOT include texi2dvi).

My `tex --version` output is

```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
Copyright 2015 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

Any help to figure out the problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks

**Edited**

My `setwd()` in `R` is

```
setwd(
  file.path(
    "/media"
    , "yaseen"
    , "D"
    , "Muhammad Yaseen"
  )
)

getwd()
[1] "/media/yaseen/D/Muhammad Yaseen"
```

and

```
texi2dvi("ABC.tex", pdf = TRUE)
```

Comment: what does `which texi2dvi` show? I'm using the same version of texlive and I have it.

Comment: In Ubuntu, `texi2dvi` is in the `texinfo` package, not in the TeX Live ones.

Comment: `texi2dvi` is provided by the `texinfo` package. make sure it's installed (`sudo apt-get install texinfo`) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652698/texi2dvi-command-not-found and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/texi2dvi.1.html

Comment: Thanks @amc and fkraiem for extending your help to solve my problem. `texinfo` package is already installed on my machine.

Comment: are you sure this is a texi2dvi problem? the error message you posted suggests that the path you provided for the file doesn't exist. does `Yaseen/XYZ` exist? if not, create it first and try again.

Comment: @amc, You absolutely right. I just tried after removing the spaces in directory names and everything works like a charm.

Comment: In past it was working for directory having spaces in their names. Now I have many directories with their names containing spaces and want to use `texi2dvi` for those directories without removing spaces in their names. Any thoughts.

Comment: @MYaseen208 what R version are you using? 3.2.4 made changes to how `texi2dvi` works, which may be a solution -- update to a more recent version (3.3.1 is latest).

Comment: @amc: I'm using `R 3.3.1`,  the latest version of `R`.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you posted suggests that the path you provided for the file doesn't exist. Does `Yaseen/XYZ` exist? if not, create it first and try again.

If your directory names contain spaces, try escaping them using `\` in the command:

```
path/to\ my\ files/
```

Or use quotes (`"` / `'`):

```
"path/to my files/"
```

If you're doing this from R, make sure you use `\\`  to ensure the escape character gets passed on:

```
texi2dvi("/media/yaseen/D/Muhammad\\ Yaseen/ABC.tex", pdf = TRUE)
```

**Edit:** note the documentation for this in R (`?texi2dvi`):

> There are various versions of the texi2dvi script on Unix-alikes and quite a number of bugs have been seen, some of which this R wrapper works around.
>
> One that was present with texi2dvi version 4.8 (as supplied on OS X) is that it will not work correctly for paths which contain spaces, nor if the absolute path to a file would contain spaces.

This is obviously a dumb bug, so the best workaround is to avoid paths with spaces.

Comment: In past it was working for directory having spaces in their names. Now I have many directories with their names containing spaces and want to use `texi2dvi` for those directories without removing spaces in their names. Any thoughts.

Comment: I tried `path/to\ my\ files/` but no success.

Comment: can you edit your question to provide the complete command in R you are using?

Comment: see my edits for `setwd()`  and `getwd()`  in `R`.

Comment: and the command to generate the pdf? try passing the complete path (with and without escape characters) to `texi2dvi()` instead of relying on `getwd()` by default.

Comment: Used `texi2dvi()` with complete path but without success when path contains spaces. However, it works fine when directory name does not contain any spaces.

Comment: Hmm... I can't reproduce, sorry..

Comment: Same error again @amc.

Comment: the workaround may be to avoid spaces in paths. it's dumb, but I'm stuck at this point and can't reproduce.